# mysql explain statement on delete cascading references

Tags: mysql, reference, foreign-keys, sql-delete, explain

I have a table 'webs' with this constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE `webs`
ADD CONSTRAINT `webs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`study_id`) REFERENCES `studies` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;`
```

I have also a table studies.
When I delete a record the table 'studies', the referenced record in webs will be also deleted. This is correct.

Now I want to check how long this operation takes and which execution plan this query has to improve the database.

For this I want to use the EXPLAIN statement.
My code is `EXPLAIN DELETE FROM`studies`WHERE id = 1048626672`

And my result is only:
[see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS44N.png)

How can I see the whole execution plan for the cascading tables?

Comment: Did you find out something? I'm wondering the same.

Comment: No, I havn't. Sorry!